# Error: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am trying to install webpart with permissions to users and groups in Microsoft Graph. I use **"@pnp/graph"** to comunicate with Microsoft Graph API.

```
 "webApiPermissionRequests": [
  {
    "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
    "scope": "User.Read.All"
  },
  {
    "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
    "scope": "Group.Read.All"
  }
]
```

I also grant permission in sharepoint admin panel to those permissions.
[image: view from sharepoint admin panel]

Also in azure active directory I see that I have permissions for both of application.

[image]
[image]

But I still have this error, week ago I was doing the same procedure without any error.
[image: view of error]

Do you have any idea what I missing?

Comment: in your `config > package-solution.json` file, modify or set the value of `isDomainIsolated` property to false, i.e set it as `"isDomainIsolated": false` and then bundle and upload the file and check

Comment: This solves the problem :) in my case.

Comment: cool, have posted that as answer. You can accept it which might help others in the community as well, cheers ! happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there seems to be some issue going on with domain isolated webparts, for the time being would suggest that you not use that property.

As mentioned in the comments, would suggest that you modify the `config > package-solution.json` file and set the `isDomainIsolated` value to false and then bundle, package and upload the solution and try again by approving the permissions.

So, simply open the `package-solution.json` file and set the value as below:

```
"isDomainIsolated": false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call method getToken with 'https://graph.windows.net' to get the JWT token
return tokenProvider.getToken('https://graph.windows.net')

You can refer to these similar situation below:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/issues/19

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3102